# In Roblox I want to create.If the player has a Tool in backpack and touches brick.Give Player 2000 cash

Tags: lua, roblox

In Roblox I want to create.If the player has a Tool in backpack and touches brick.Give Player 2000
cash,and tool dispears.I already have made a leaderboard for the cash,and already have my tool in server storoge.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can start by using a `.Touched` event which fires every time an object is touched. A `.Touched` event can carry one parameter; the object that touched it. For example, if a player (R15) stepped on a block on the floor, the object that hit the part might be `Left Foot`. Here is what the skeleton of a `.Touched` function looks like:

```
<Part>.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     print(hit.Name) --As per the example above, this would print "Left Foot"
end)
```

Since any object can touch the part, but not every one has a Backpack, you'll want to first check if the object that hit your part is from an actual player. You can do this by looking for a `Humanoid`, which would be a sibling of the part that touched. You can do this by adding:

```
<Part>.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
          print(hit.Name) --As per the example above, this would print "Left Foot"
     end
end)
```

Now that we have verified that a player was what touched our part, we can use the function of `game.Players` called `GetPlayerFromCharacter()`. A `Character` is just your player in `game.workspace`, so by calling this function, it gets your player in `game.Players` from your character. This is similar to `game.Players:FindFirstChild(<Player>.Name)`. Either one work, but I will be using the first one for this example. Added to your code, here is what it should now look like:

```
<Part>.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
          local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
     end
end)
```

As you may know, `Backpack` is a direct child of the player in `game.Players`, so we can use `player.Backpack` to find our Backpack. Now we can do the same thing that we did to check for a `humanoid`, to check for our `tool`:

```
<Part>.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
          local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
          local Backpack = player.Backpack
          if Backpack:FindFirstChild("<Tool Name>") then
               player.leaderstats.<Money>.Value += 2000 --Gives them 2000 cash
          end
     end
end)
```

If you cloned the tool into the player's Backpack previously, you can do `Backpack.<Tool Name>:Destroy()` to get rid of it/make it dissapear.